# How to delete directory/file named "-f", "-r" or other in terminal

Tags: command-line, rm

Just wondering how to delete directory/file named "**-f**", "**-r**" or other using terminal.

Comment: @user535733 it's not hard. You can trivially do it from a graphical file manager or, from the command line with `mkdir somedir/-f` or `touch somedir/-r` or `touch -- -r` etc.

Answer (score 5):

This is literally [in the manual](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/rm.1.html)

> To remove a file whose name starts with a '-',  for  example  '-foo',  use  one  of  these       commands:
>
> ```
>          rm -- -foo
>          rm ./-foo
> ```

Answer (score 4):

The `rm` command supports a `--` option, which tells it that any further arguments that begin with `-` should be taken literally and are not to be treated as option flags. eg:

```
rm -- -r
```

Many other Unix commands support something similar, and it's an out-of-the-box feature of the commonly-used `getopt` utility which is often used for command option parsing.

Note that quoting the file name, eg `rm "-r"` does *not* work (whereas quoting does help when you're trying to delete a file called, say, `*` (asterisk), eg `rm "*"`). That's because the wildcard expansion is being handled by the your Unix shell *before* your command is invoked, and quoting disables such expansion. But options are effectively normal arguments that the command program (eg `rm`) itself gets to decide what to do with - they aren't "special" to the shell, so quoting has no effect.